# Datatable double ajax request on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the Datatable plugin. I have a page that is loaded with AJAX. When I click anywhere in the page another AJAX request is fired from the Datatable

```js
let datatable = $('#results').DataTable({
  language: language,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "/app/admin/AdminUsersAjax",
    type: 'POST'
  },
  lengthMenu: [
    [25, 50, 100],
    [25, 50, 100]
  ],
  columns: [{
    data: 'email',
    searchable: true,
    sortable: true
  }, {
    data: 'name',
    searchable: true,
    sortable: true
  }, {
    data: 'active',
    searchable: false,
    sortable: true
  }, {
    data: 'date',
    searchable: false,
    sortable: true
  }, {
    data: 'actions',
    searchable: false,
    sortable: false
  }],
  responsive: true,
  drawCallback: () => {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  },
  dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
    "<'table-responsive table-custom-container my-3'tr>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5 text-muted'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
});
```

Comment: Do you have any other code which is invoking this code on each click?  Can you provide a more complete example which demonstrates the problem, either in the question or as a link to an external page?

Comment: @David no The datatable is calling itself I do not know why,I will try to make ajax call and append data inside table